# How do you change a setting in TYPO3 Setup based on a Constant?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

In my constants I have a select dropdown with two options.

In my setup can I change the `page.shortcutIcon` setting depending on what that constant is set to?

Also, can I use the same constant to determine a setting in PageTSConfig or the rte .yaml config?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to use Typoscript Template Constants (frontend).

In PageTS (Backend configuration)

Thr backend does not need and does not evaluate the configuration there.

Comment: Ok, that's a shame. What about the `page.shortcutIcon` in setup? is there some way to use an if statement for it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add an additional field to the `pages` record for your new value?
This value can be evaluated in the PageTS for backend conditions.
And it could be evaluated in the frontend. either in the regular typoscript setup (use data instead of constants) or in FLUID as field of your `pages`data.

Comment: An interesting idea, but I would need it to work for a whole page tree. This could only work for a single page wouldn't it?

Comment: you can declare fields to be inherited (keywords: slide, levelfield). so a given value can be accessed also in pages below. That is a little bit more complicated than just the accessing the simple field, but is possible too. see fields: `backend_layout` / `backend_layout_next_level` which decide the backend layout for a page tree with the option for each page to have it's own layout. And this fields also can determine the frontend layout.